# MS SQL Server. Transpose columns of data to rows of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a Details table which can be described by the following:

```
Create table #Details (
Id int identity,
HeaderId int,
ChannelId int,
Value float
)
```

We insert some seed data:

```
insert into #Details (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(1, 0, 1019.51)
insert into #Details (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(1, 1, 20.1)
insert into #Details (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(1, 2, 21.2)
insert into #Details (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(1, 3, 22.3)
insert into #Details (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(1, 4, 23.4)

insert into #Details (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(2, 0, 1020.62)
insert into #Details (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(2, 1, 26.1)
insert into #Details (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(2, 2, 27.2)
insert into #Details (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(2, 3, 28.3)
insert into #Details (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(2, 4, 29.4)
```

Select All produces the following:

[image]

I would like to transpose the column data to rows, to produce the output below:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database? Does `Channelld` contain only  0,1,2,3,4 values or you can have more? If not you can use PIVOT in SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server.  I thought you could use pivot, but I am not getting the query right.  Hence the posing of the question here.  Thanks.

Comment: If you know that the values of `0,1,2,3,4` are going to be used in the pivot ahead of time, then a plain old `pivot` is the way to go. If you don't know what the values of the column headers will be before running the sql, then you'll want to do a `Dynamic Pivot`. You'll have to let us know which scenario fits here to get a proper answer as the solution will be a bit different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. Just select first `HeaderId,value, ChannelId` in  a subquery and then pivot.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Id int identity,
HeaderId int,
ChannelId int,
Value float)

insert into @tbl (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(1, 0, 1019.51)
insert into @tbl (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(1, 1, 20.1)
insert into @tbl (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(1, 2, 21.2)
insert into @tbl (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(1, 3, 22.3)
insert into @tbl (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(1, 4, 23.4)

insert into @tbl (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(2, 0, 1020.62)
insert into @tbl (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(2, 1, 26.1)
insert into @tbl (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(2, 2, 27.2)
insert into @tbl (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(2, 3, 28.3)
insert into @tbl (HeaderId, ChannelId, Value) values(2, 4, 29.4)

SELECT * 
FROM
    (
    SELECT HeaderId,value, ChannelId
        FROM
    @tbl
    )T
PIVOT
    (
        SUM(value)

        FOR ChannelId IN ([0],[1], [2], [3], [4]

    )
) AS PivotTable;
```

Result below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I'd missed HeaderId from the query!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select HeaderId
  , [0] as ChannelId0
  , [1] as ChannelId1
  , [2] as ChannelId2
    , [3] as ChannelId3
      , [4] as ChannelId4
from
(
  select HeaderId, ChannelId,Value
  from #Details
) x
pivot
(
  max(Value)
  for ChannelId in([0],[1],[2], [3],[4],[5])
)p
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'd missed HeaderId from the query!